# Input type number equivalent to step=0

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I need an input with only a number so I put type="number". Then it needs not to increase or decrease when the users use the keyboard (because with this event I need to do other stuff and I don't want to make +1 or -1 by myself).

I searched for a clean way to do this. I need a comment about step=0 but it doesn't work. In fact, I'm surprised there is no property to do it easily.

Answer (score 1):

you can prevent the native behaviour :

```
document.getElementById('yourInputID').addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
    if (e.which === 38 || e.which === 40) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add an attribute to the input like so:

```
<input type="number" onwheel="this.blur()" />
```

This will disable the scroll

Answer (score 0):

If you want to block increase and decrease on key pressed, use the @HostListener to listen to events on your document.

```
@HostListener('document:keypress', [$event])
      function (event: KeyboardEvent) {
        // you block the increase and decrease here
      });
```

I'm not 100% sure with the synthax of events, you might want to dig a little on that, but @HostListener seems to be the best option

Also do you +1 -1 on the already inputed value, inside this component, or in the upper component before the input ?

Comment: Your solution is for me the clearest one. The problem is when I caught the event is too late. The value of the input is already changed